# Three.js Javascript object transformation issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, dom-events

I'm trying to scale height(y) of a cube as well as raising its y position simultaneously so that its base remains on the same x-z plane even after scaling. The rendering works fine but it is not working as expected. The object position increases rapidly in Y and then it starts disappearing. Can anyone help me out?

I've added an `eventListener`: `mouseMove` and its listener function to do the above transformations:

```
var fHeight = 5, yShift;
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
                    var mouseVector = new THREE.Vector3(2*(event.clientX/window.innerWidth) - 1, 1 - 2*(event.clientY/window.innerHeight));
                    var projector = new THREE.Projector();
                    var raycaster = projector.pickingRay(mouseVector.clone(), camera);
                    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( Object.children );
                    if(intersects.length > 0) {
                    intersects[0].object.scale.y += 0.1;
                    fHeight = fHeight*intersects[0].object.scale.y;
                    yShift = fHeight/2 - intersects[0].object.position.y - 2.5;
                    intersects[0].object.position.y = intersects[0].object.position.y + yShift;                                 
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the vertices of your cube so its base sticks to its y=0 plane.

Then `object.scale.y` will directly modify the cube height only, without displacing the base, and you will not have to reposition the object.

Hope it helps